# Help on dualboot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 on HP Mini 200?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, hp

All I am trying to do is dualboot the latest Ubuntu and Windows 7 on my fairly new HP Mini 200. I am using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xK8X7_tYWmA for guidance. I have "partitioned" (set aside) 15GB of space to install Ubuntu.

Here is a link to a photo of the installation process I am currently stuck at.

[image]

I don't know what to do from here. Should I delete /dev/sda4 (HP Tools)?? If so, how?? 
 Apparently it contains the BIOS part of the startup menu...

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Start at the [UEFI Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: I'm not sure he has uefi

Comment: Hi and welcome to this site. This is not exactly a forum, but a Q&A site. Please [take the tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) to see how it's different.

Comment: > Apparently it contains the BIOS part of the startup menu... indicates UEFI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `gparted` and create an ext4 partition in that space you opened up, also there is no BIOS part of the disk, there is an MBR but that is not a partition and is not accessible from `gparted` or anything else. Once you have created the ext4 partition you restart the installation (sorry) and once you get to the screen you posted you select that partition, click "change" then set it as ext4, format, and set it as mount point `/`, then continue the installation following the prompts.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have honestly saved me hours of searching the web! :) I could not have done it without you! :)

Comment: I've seen a lot of those problems where it marks it as unavailable when it is really just unpartitioned, I'm thinking of filing a bug complaint

Comment: Good idea, go ahead @sbergeron

Comment: How do I create an ext4 partition in my 15gb space I opened up please?? @sbergeron

Comment: click partition then format as ext4, then restart the installer and it should show up

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a system that boots via BIOS and that uses MBR partitions. MBR is limited to four "primary" partitions, and you've used all of them. MBR does support an essentially limitless number of "logical" partitions, but to use them, you must have a special type of primary partition called an "extended" partition, which you don't have. You have two options:

- You can delete one or more of the existing primary partitions and use it to create new primary partitions for Ubuntu and/or create an extended partition and then create logical partitions within it.
- You can use [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) to convert one or more of your primary partitions into logical partitions. (FixParts will create the necessary extended partition as part of this process.) You'll then be able to create new logical partitions for Linux. Note that there are limitations on what you can convert. Also, Windows must boot from a primary partition. Thus, you may need to do some juggling to get this to work. (The FixParts documentation describes the issues in detail.)

If your computer supports EFI-mode booting, you could re-install Windows in EFI mode, or convert it to boot in that way. In EFI mode, you'll use the GUID Partition Table (GPT), which doesn't have the 4-primary-partition limit of MBR. Most computers sold since mid-2011 support EFI, although prior to the release of Windows 8, many manufacturers continued to use BIOS-mode booting.